# Why do I get "Unresolved reference: platform" when using the firebase-bom dependency with KMM

Tags: firebase, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kmm

When I attempt to add the Firebase-bom dependency using the following block in a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project's shared module, the word `platform` appears in red error text and the Gradle build fails with "Unresolved reference: platform." How can I resolve this so it builds correctly?

```
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1"))
                implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer lies in [KT-40489](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40489).

The `platform()` function used to import the Firebase Bill of Materials is not available in Kotlin Multiplatform plugin’s `KotlinDependencyHandler` but only in Gradle’s standard `DependencyHandler`. It also does not seem that a fix is coming soon. As a result, you need to specify Gradle's handler explicitly.

Here are two workarounds:

```
val androidMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(project.dependencies.platform("..."))
    }
}
```

OR

```
val androidMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        "jvmMainImplementation"(platform("...))
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm this should be marked as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: For js source sets use "jsMainImplementation" instead.